# SQL Compare between rows and columns in same query

Tags: sql-server

i have a table as shown below-tblMatch.Here i am comparing each custId vs MCustID to check who is having the oldest date and based on the result i am updating a master table active flag using the update query shown below.Instead of making update immediately after each row, i would like to make the update only after comparison between rows  where a potential a=b=c scenario exists(here a=b and a=c that means a=c. Here below for eg: we can see 200 and 300 are related via 100 but after the first row update 100 is inactive and i would like to do an additional comparison between 200 and 300 to make sure which is greater. I believe a CTE should resolve the issue. Could you please help on this?

```
 ID   CustID    MCustID Date        MDate
   1    100     200     2017-01-10  2017-01-15 
   2    100     300     2017-01-10  2017-01-07
update A
set active = 0
from Cust A inner join tblMatch M
on A.CustomerID = case when M.Date < M.MDate then M.CustId else M.MCustId end
```

Comment: So basically anything that isn't the overall maximum date/mdate should have active set to 0?

Comment: yes that is correct. if there is no a=b=c relationship then update can be done by comparing just a=b

Comment: What is the issue with your current query?

Comment: Hello Tim, currently it is not doing the a=b=c comparison scenarios, its working fine for comparison between 2 columns in a single row.

Comment: Please update your question with data showing what the problem is.  From the data and query you showed us so far, everything is fine.

Comment: I don't think you need a recursive CTE for this. You just need something like `SELECT * FROM Cust WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CASE WHEN Date > MDate THEN MCustID ELSE CustID END FROM tblMatch);` I believe. This should pull all the customer IDs that aren't the highest.

Comment: Tim- I am trying to get a solid example. ZLK, in that case as Tim mentioned my current update should handle that i believe

Comment: Then your current query handles an "a=b=c" scenario. Because the highest (let's say "c") will never show up but a and b will.

Comment: hi Tim and ZLK i have updated the question to reflect the implicit a=b=c scenario. Now what would be the best way to compare 200 and 300. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: will a SQL lag() and lead() help here? i am using sql 2012 r2, otherwise add rownumber by partition on Custid, Not sure though.